# Delay displaying array objects multiple hours after created

Tags: reactjs

I've got a project in React that I'm working on where I create events based on TV shows. Obviously, with how timezones and air times work in the US we have a show that airs 8pm ET/PT which means it airs at 8pm eastern and 8pm pacific, but 8pm pacific is actually 3 hours after 8pm eastern. So whenever a user in eastern time zone visits my page I'm creating those events as they happen live and the user sees them as they come in. By the time the TV show airs in pacific time I will already have all of the events logged, but want it to feel like they are being logged in real time like the eastern time user.

Do I just need to use setInterval to check the existing array that I have every couple seconds to see if anything in that array should be shown.

I'm sorry if this is super confusing, but basically I have an existing array with created at times and want to delay showing them to a pacific time user based on how long ago that array item was created.

Comment: May be you can get time zone of end user and based on that you can hide or show your items.

Comment: @AmanSadhwani yeah that was my initial thought behind it, but my question was more how I'd implement it? I'm guessing I'm going to grab the entire array from the back end and then have an interval set and whenever that time has been 3 hours in the past, then I'd just update and show those array objects

Comment: why need for set interval ? can't we have that time info from backend and based on that you can keep validation on front end ?